# Providing service for angular template in a place of inserting

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-template, angular-providers

I'm struggling with an issue that it seems that injected service for the angular component which is inside a `ng-template` is determined by the location and providers of the parent component of the template. I want to provide another service in a place where I do use the template and not where I define it.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hvtj2b?file=src/app/app.component.ts

As you can see in the demo, both components have the same service injected. It somehow ignores the `providers` section in the `Component2` definition. Is there any other way to provide the service to the template other than using template context and then proxying it to component via input?

Comment: This is working as expected. `ComponentWithServiceComponent` doesn't have any providers, so it uses the module provider. If you injected `SomeService` into `Component2Component`, you would get an instance of `SpecialService`.

Comment: If I inject `SomeService` into `Component2Component` I do get `SpecialService`, but only in `Component2Component`. What I do want to achieve is to provide it further up to `ComponentWithServiceComponent`.

Comment: I see what you're trying to achieve, just explaining why it's not working as you want it to. So how should the decision be made about which implementation to inject into various components? Can you explain a bit more about why you are taking this approach?

Comment: I've got a component that after clicking a button it sets a specific date to a corresponding input. In one case I want it not to be specific date, but a token which represents the date. I tought that since I do have a service to provide that date it would be ok to just limit the scope with a custom one using the approach from https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-with-components

Comment: I mean, limiting scopes is working for me in all the other cases. The only issue is with the template. Like I've said in the question - it seems that the template is using providers based on the parent component it is defined in and not the component that displays it

Comment: Can you link to articles or docs you've read that gave you the idea of this approach? I'm curious to see what is said

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#scenario-specialized-providers
I've also modified the demo so it's more clear that the host component of the template is determining the service

Comment: The pattern in the example you linked is not the same pattern as your demo. In your demo, `ComponentWithServiceComponent` has no providers, so uses the more generic provider from the module. It's a simple as that. The example you linked would have the child components declaring the providers that get injected.

Comment: The example in the link is more like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fqgdqw The provider declarations in the components apply to what's being injected into that same component.

Comment: if you remove the providers from the `ComponentC` in your example you'll see that it's getting the service provided by ComponentB, not module. That's exactly how it's working and that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve, apart from the fact that it does not work with templates the way I though it would

Comment: Ah, I see what you're trying to achieve. Yes, I'm would be very suprised if it worked in the way you were hoping.